# to find co-prime with 7 from [-10,10]

Tags: coprime

How many integers in [-10,10] are co-prime with 7?

I find that prime belongs to N, so my answer is 9(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10).

can you give me advice?

Comment: As $7$ is prime, just remove from the given interval all multiples of $7$ (including negative ones).

Comment: definition coprime:  (also written co-prime) if the only positive integer (factor) that divides both of them is 1. so I think negative ones are not in it.

Comment: Why? $1$ divides  negative numbers as well.

Comment: According to the definition, coprime belongs to positive integers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but only prime numbers are defined as belonging to natural numbers. That is done to ensure uniqueness in the prime factors decomposition. There is no uniqueness involved in defining coprime numbers. Their definition can be extended to coprime ideals in rings.

Comment: Wow, you are right, and I got it. Thanks!